# How to instantiate by generic type?

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to instantiate the class that is provided as generic type parameter in an abstract class?

Example:

```
public MyClass {
    public MyClass(String test) {

    }
}
```

Is it possible to instantiate this class inside another abstract class?

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T extends MyClass> {
    public AbstractClass() {
        T t = new T("test"); //Cannot instantiate the type T
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that straight-forward.

You need a `Class<T>` that will hold the generic type after type erasure.

Then, you have to invoke [`Class#getDeclaredConstructor(Class< ? > .. params)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) to trigger the desired constructor and create new instance dynamically. For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T extends MyClass> {
    public AbstractClass(Class<T> clazz) {
        T t = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance("test");
    }
}
```